# dd command lost partition

Tags: dd

When I used to image my USB, I used the `dd` command and saved that image to my Hard Disk

my USB = sdb1 (4 GB) My partation = sda5 (775 GB free space)

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/sda5
```

operation completed. my USB 4 GB take my 775 GB. :(

I lost my 775 GB. How to restore and how to make?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is your problem that you had data on `/dev/sda5` and it's gone? Or is it that you had an unused 775GB partition, and you copied 4GB to it but now you want to use the remaining 771GB for something else?

Answer (score 4):

You saved the image to your harddisk not by creating a 4Gb file in the filesystem mounted on the partition /dev/sda5, but by overwriting the filesystem there
with the filesystem on your USB.

You should restore that partition from your backup. It might be that NTFS has information beyond the first 4GB that allows recovery of the rest of the disc, but the fist 4Gb have been overwritten for sure, and it is unlikely that that part of the sda5 partition did not contain data.

Comment: How can i restore that 773 GB partation.
How can i find my backup ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: @bakie That depends on the way you made the backup.

Comment: If I format sda5 , can I get 775 GB ? bro

Comment: Yes, but you would not get the data back that used to be on there (before you did the dd). If it was empty, or the data not important, you can format it and AFAIK should get a 775Gb partition, the info about the partition size is in the MBR and that did **not** get overwritten.

Comment: Dear bro, How can i restore my data?
Which method is the best for my problem?

I have no backup ?

Will i restore from window or Linux or live CD ?
Which software is best for that case.

Thansk a lot bro . Data is important for me.

Comment: Now My sda5 is just 4 GB.
but in Disk utility, sda5 show 773 GB like above my picture.

Will i recovery before formatting that sda5 ?
After formatted sda5, will i recovery my data ?

Comment: @bakie If you don't have a backup, you cannot restore. You can try to **recover** the data, but I have no clue how to do that on an NTFS partition and/or how to do that under Windows (you might have more luck finding someone on superuser). Whatever you do make a backup of the sda5 (in the original size), or better of the whole sda drive, before you start trying to recover.

Comment: And like I already indicated, if you restore, the data that was in the first 4Gb of that partition will be gone.

Comment: Sorry I could not do more. Where did you read/learn about using `dd` that way?